# Is there a way to find all items that fit a mathematic equation?

Tags: mongodb

I want to create a query that will return every document that fits a given mathematic equation.

My goal is given a document's id, I will return every document whose value's `AND` the given document's value is larger than 0.
For example, if this is the DB:

```js
[
    {
        "_id": 1,
        "value": 24
    },
    {
        "_id": 2,
        "value": 32
    },
    {
        "_id": 3,
        "value": 56
    },
]
```

Given the id 1, I want to return only 3.
If this is impossible in mongo, I would like to get recommendations for a DB which fits this action

Answer (score 0):

If you use map/reduce you could probably perform the calculations on the server side. You'll still be performing full collection scans, rephrasing your formula to produce the _id you want will give you faster queries.